# Task had a not serializable result in spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to read cassandra table using the cassandra driver to the spark.
Here is  the code.

```
val x = 1 to 2
val rdd = sc.parallelize(x)

val query = "Select data from testkeyspace.testtable where id=%d"

val cc = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf)

val res1 =
    rdd.map{ it => 
            cc.withSessionDo{ session =>
            session.execute( query.format(it))
        }
     }

res1.take(1).foreach(println)
```

but I am getting the exception Task had a not serializable result.

```
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1.0 in stage 24.0 (TID 77) had a not serializable result: com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$SinglePage
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

How to Solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-serializable object in our transformation is the result coming back from Cassandra, which is an iterable on the query result.
You typically want to materialize that collection into the RDD.

One way would be to ask all records resulting from that query:

```
session.execute( query.format(it)).all()
```

Comment: even if I do all I am getting the same exception. "task had a not serializable result"

Comment: @Knight71 with the same cause?

Comment: This time with different datatype.
`org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) had a not serializable result: com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedRow; not retrying
.org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) had a not serializable result: com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedRow`

Comment: @Knight71 then follow the breadcrumb: `https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/ArrayBackedRow.java` is not serializable. The idea is that the object created by the `map` operation needs to be serializable. You will need to transform that `Row` into some serializable form: e.g. `session.execute(query.format(it)).one().getXXXXX("data")`  (not sure what 'data' is)

Comment: @maasg this message cannot occur in other case? I'm using a not serializable object in my function but I'm not returning this, I also have this error message.

Comment: @crak - it's probably still being referred from the object graph of the object you are returning