# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, streaming

here is my code :

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

      val lines = stream.map(_._2)
      lines.print()
      lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
        rdd.foreach( data =>
          if (data != null) {
            println(data.toString)
            val records = data.toString
            CassandraConnector(conf).withSessionDo {
              session =>
                session.execute("INSERT INTO propatterns_test.meterreadings JSON "+records+";")
            }
          }
        )
      }
```

so where i am going wrong.

my error log is :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2037)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:874)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:873)
    at etc.
```

I am storing rdd message into cassandra.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704659/task-had-a-not-serializable-result-in-spark

Comment: no, i want to fire query when i got message in rdd.

Comment: Is `CassandraConnector` serializable?

Comment: how can i make it serializable

Comment: Yes it is: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/CassandraConnector.scala

Comment: how can i use that in this code

Comment: You've cut logs, at the bottom there is info about what class cannot be serialized